# How does .NET compare strings exactly?

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

How does string comparison work exactly? -this is something I've wondered for a while.

- Does C# check the length of each string before checking each character?
- Or does it start looping through and comparing each character individually first?
- Does it continue checking each character even if one character is different, or does it stop after one character is found to be different?
- Or does it not even loop through each character directly?

I know it's a very open-ended bunch of questions but it's something that I haven't been able to find any answers for.

Any answers are appreciated, as well as docs. Cheers!

Comment: It's important to distinguish between the different types of string comparison available to you. I believe the basic `a == b` comparison is just a code-by-code comparison, and yes, this will check length first, but the others, for instance available through the `StringComparer` class, cannot. For instance, in my culture the following two strings are considered equal: `Lasse` and `Laße`, if I use `StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(...)`, it will return `true`. Obviously the two strings does not have the same number of characters.

Comment: Did you try to look it up? ALL of .NET is public - there are the reference sources for older versions. The newer versions (core) are on github. Just look up the string class. This is not open ended - this is asking us to read the documentation for you.

Comment: @TomTom I did, though I don't think I phrased it in a way that Google would've given me the source to string.cs in .NET. Something I'll definitely keep in mind in the future. I still nonetheless appreciate the responses given.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but you can always take a look and consult the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) as a precursor to asking questions about implementation-details of .NET.  Or look on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core) for .NET Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e. Yes, it does check for length first.

```
    // Determines whether two strings match.
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == null)                        //this is necessary to guard against reverse-pinvokes and
            throw new NullReferenceException();  //other callers who do not use the callvirt instruction

        String str = obj as String;
        if (str == null)
            return false;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        if (this.Length != str.Length)
            return false;

        return EqualsHelper(this, str);
    }

    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    private unsafe static bool EqualsHelper(String strA, String strB)
    {
        Contract.Requires(strA != null);
        Contract.Requires(strB != null);
        Contract.Requires(strA.Length == strB.Length);

        int length = strA.Length;

        fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
        {
            char* a = ap;
            char* b = bp;

            // unroll the loop
#if AMD64
            // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
            // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code
            // than the 32 bit case and is shorter
            // pathlength

            while (length >= 12)
            {
                if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) return false;
                if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) return false;
                if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) return false;
                a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
            }
#else
            while (length >= 10)
            {
                if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) return false;
                a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
            }
#endif

            // This depends on the fact that the String objects are
            // always zero terminated and that the terminating zero is not included
            // in the length. For odd string sizes, the last compare will include
            // the zero terminator.
            while (length > 0) 
            {
                if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
                a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
            }

            return (length <= 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: THe most simple and trivial answer: Check the reference sources.

Comment: From my understanding of the source, it seems to check the length then loop until it finds a char that differs in one string or another. Sort of what I figured, but languages can sometimes do things weird. Especially when it comes to strings.

Comment: @Cornelius Yes, but remember .NET is a single platform and library used by multiple different languages.

Comment: @Dai So are you saying that the implementation can differ depending upon the language? If so that's very interesting, to say the least.

Comment: @Cornelius No, quite the opposite: It's safe to assume that all programming languages that target .NET (such as C#, VB.NET, F#, C++/CLI, etc) will use the same string type (`System.String`) and thus use the same string comparisons (`Object.ReferenceEquals`, `String.Equals` and `StringComparer`). This assumption is not always absolutely strictly true (e.g. because some languages do let you define your own custom String type, or if you're using String-like types such as `Char[]`, `StringBuilder`, `Span<Char>`, etc).

Comment: @Dai Oh, I understand, my apologies. I often forget that C# and .NET are essentially one entity.

Comment: @Cornelius C# is a language that targets the .NET framework, just like F# or VB.NET for example. When those high level languages get compiled, it's all the same CIL code underneath.